# Can we change the profile using trigger when new user create

Tags: trigger

```
trigger ChangetheProfile on User (after insert) {
    profile p=[select id, name from profile where name='HydComp'];
    profile pp=[select id, name from Profile where name='HydComPhy'];
    list<user> uu=new list<user>();
    for(User u:trigger.new){
        if(u.ProfileId == p.id){
            u.profileId= pp.id;
            uu.add(u);
        }
    }
    update uu;
}
```

I write this code this one is not working

Comment: It's better to do something like this in a before trigger, that way you won't have to update the records again. Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can update the profile of a User.
I executed below code in Developer console and it worked.

```
User u1 = [Select id from User where id ='00520000003TyOB'];
u1.profileId= '00e20000001Pb2e';

Update u1;
```

Now, you should fire your trigger on `before insert` Event.

```
trigger ChangetheProfile on User (before insert) {
    profile p=[select id, name from profile where name='HydComp' LIMIT 1];
    profile pp=[select id, name from Profile where name='HydComPhy' LIMIT 1];

    for(User u:trigger.new){
        if(u.ProfileId == p.id){
            u.profileId= pp.id;

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

Always remember when you want to update a field on the same Object trigger written on it, it requires "Before" event.

**Resolution:**

In this case, we just need to change the event from "After" to "Before" and remove the DML Update as it already been taken care of.

```
trigger ChangetheProfile on User (Before insert) {
for(User u:trigger.new){
u.ProfileId = *Id_of_Profile*;
}
}
```